# A misconception about arbitary constant

Tags: calculus, limits, constants

Given a function $f(x)$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, If $f'(x)=0$ $\text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R$. Then $f(x)=C$.(This is my understanding)

Question:

I think that $C$ has to remain constant for $\text{ for all } x\in\mathbb R$. But this is not valid for $f(x)= $$\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}$. clearly $f'(x)=0$ but $C$ doesn't remain constant. For all real positive numbers its$\frac{\pi}{2}$ while for -ve real numbers its $\frac{-\pi}{2}$. I just don't understand it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That $f$ isn't defined at $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thanks, So $f'(0)=0$ is invalid?

Comment: In any case, you would need $f'$ to be zero for all $x$ - you don't have this!

Comment: Yes. Since $f$ isn't defined at $0$, $f'(0)$ has no meaning.

Comment: @Syn No $f'(0)=0$ is not valid. It's not that it is false. But it isn't true either. It's something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GitGud, "Neither true nor false",I don't understand it.

Comment: @Syn I don't think it is a good idea to go into that. But for something to be true (or false), it must, first of all, make sense.But $f'(0)$ is something that doesn't exist. You can't meaningfully say it equals or differs anything.

Comment: @GitGud Sorry to bother you,I created the graph with desmos.The "slope" of the graph is always $0$. Even at $0$

Comment: @Sin No worries. Slopes are merely intuitive devices one uses to think that things. You need to use the definition. The definition of $f'(0)$ is that it equals $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right)$ if this limit exists. But what is $f(0)$? You can't compute the limit.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks. I get it at last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $g'(x) = 0$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for a real function $g$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$, the function $g$ should be differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \textrm{arctan}(x) + \textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does, however, not exist in $x = 0$.

Comment: And it might be useful to point out that the constants will be the same in $]-\infty ,0[$ and $]0,+\infty[$, considered separately.